# Regex Parsing Kafka Listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm listening to a Kafka Topic and receiving the messages, comparing them to an object and then trying to parse the message. I'm receiving a number of messages about one search, and I'm just trying to get this one

---

`userName:User.Name userId:FDF3JH4 session:9cf2-21-c6-28-c360f1edba53 searchString:test, searchType:DEFAULT_SEARCH` and this is what I want my

---

LogPattern to be `String logPattern = ".*(userName:)(\\S+)\\s(userId:)(\\S+)\\s(session:)(\\S+)\\s(searchString:)([^,]).*";`

```
    if (isValidObject) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logPattern);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(historyRequest.getLog());

        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            return;
        }
```

I setup a test function to make sure the message I received and my pattern was correct, but when I put it into the actual function, it doesn't work. It returns no results for `String logPattern = ".*";` But, the strange thing is, when messing around with the log patterns, I was able to get a match of a kafka message with this log pattern and this log:

---

`String logPattern = ".*[userName]\\:(\\S+)\\s\\w+:(\\S+)(\\s\\S+\\s\\w+\\:)([^,]+).*";`

---

`userName:User.Name userId:D394H4 session:3f1da-0c-fb-90-949a searchString:"test" took:13.0 page:1 resultSize:1 sponsored:false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near as I can tell you had a matching pattern.  I'm guessing it didn't do exactly what you wanted, because it didn't pick up the `searchString` argument.   I've posted some code below with a slightly modified version of your pattern.  I did two things to it:

1. I eliminated the parentheses around the constant text
2. I fixed the pattern to match all text after `searchString` up to the comma

Here's the code:

```
public class Logtest {

    String logPattern_orig = ".*(userName:)(\\S+)\\s(userId:)(\\S+)\\s(session:)(\\S+)\\s(searchString:)([^,]).*";
    String logPattern = ".*userName:(\\S+)\\suserId:(\\S+)\\ssession:(\\S+)\\ssearchString:([^,]*),.*";

    String kafkaMsg = "userName:User.Name userId:FDF3JH4 session:9cf2-21-c6-28-c360f1edba53 searchString:test, searchType:DEFAULT_SEARCH";

    void test() {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logPattern);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(kafkaMsg);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Matches!");
            for (int i=1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + "='" + matcher.group(i) + "'");
            }
        }

    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Logtest lt = new Logtest();
        lt.test();
    }

}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
Matches!
Group 1='User.Name'
Group 2='FDF3JH4'
Group 3='9cf2-21-c6-28-c360f1edba53'
Group 4='test'
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out there was a new line `\n` in the kafka message which is the reason I wasn't able to find a match.